# The method onCreate(bundle) is undefined for the object type

Tags: android, super

Hi i am new to android dev, the following code gives error
1) The method onCreate(bundle) is undefined for the object type
 2) The method onCreate(bundle) of type DisplayMessageActivity must be override or implement a supertype method
I am using super.onCreate but it is giving me this error?

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Get the message from the intent
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                        // Create the text view
                TextView textView = new TextView(null);
                textView.setTextSize(40);
                textView.setText(message);

                // Set the text view as the activity layout
                setContentView(textView);

            // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                // Show the Up button in the action bar.
                ((Object) getActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
    }
        private void setContentView(TextView textView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        private Intent getIntent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        private Object getActionBar() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am using this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method undefined error in Android Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067653/method-undefined-error-in-android-activity)

Comment: @RandolphCarter Usually the newer question should be flagged as the duplicate of the older and not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

You have forgotten to extend Activity class.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity
```

If you want to create an Activity then you must extend the Activity as super class. To learn more about the basic of activity see [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) here

Comment: Correct but maybe a little explanation would help the OP learn and help themselves in the future

Comment: @codeMagic,, thanks.. Can you suggest what will be the best answer for this kind of question? please edit my one or post new if possible

Comment: No, I think your edit did a pretty good job. Unless you want to expand on how the OP is creating a method called `getIntent()` which doesn't appear to be correct, unless I missed something there. I started an edit on your answer but I realized it was more of an expanded answer

Comment: but i am using this tutorial and getIntent() is created correctly according to the tutorial.Can you please explain this in detail?

Comment: Where in that do you see ` private Intent getIntent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }`?

Comment: getIntent , SetContentView these methods are the member of Activity Class. You need not define them unless you have to ovverride them to give some extra features

Comment: It gives the same error with the following code
public class DisplayMessageActivity  {
 
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Get the message from the intent
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

     // Create the text view
      TextView textView = new TextView(this);
      textView.setTextSize(40);
      textView.setText(message);

      // Set the text view as the activity layout
      setContentView(textView);

Comment: Clean your project, display what the current error is, and show how you are starting this `Activity` from `MainActivity`

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

Comment: cont...
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }
Cont...

Comment: cont..
public void sendMessage(View view) {
     // Do something in response to button
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
   startActivity(intent);
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

@StinePike's answers fixes your immediate problem. But you also need to read about [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)s. These are basically just a way to send messages. It is an implicit action in that it doesn't start something but tells something what to do and how to handle certain data. I say this because I believe you are misled in that you have a function called `getIntent()`. This doesn't need to be a function in your class but this is how you receive data if this `Activity` is started with an `Intent`.

Say you start an `Activity` like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);  // MyActivity is the Activity you are currently in and NextActivity is the Activity you are starting
intent.putExtra("people", "Fred");  // This isn't necessary but a way to pass data. I put "Fred" but this could be a String variable or something else
startActivity(intent);
```

In `NextActivity` you might do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    Intent recIntent = getIntent();  // this gets the intent information sent from MyActivity
    String data = recIntent.getStringExtra("people");  // data now equals  the String Fred
}
```

no need for you to create a function called `getIntent()`, it is a native function. So when you use `getIntent()` it is a good idea to check for `null` in case this `Activity` wasn't started with an `Intent`. Maybe it was the launcher `Activity`

Comment: My problem is not solved, i am fcaing the same error with the following code. using intent in the same manner
public class DisplayMessageActivity  {
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Get the message from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

Comment: If you followed StinePikes advice and extended Activity then you shouldn't be getting the same error that you posted

Answer (score 0):

**Change:** `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

**To:** `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

I was working on the same tutorial. I copied the code from the tutorial directly and ran the app (which worked). So set off to check the differences and this is the only one I found.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding!!