# Method undefined error in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to make a simple Android application based on a guide. I am using the code below, but it is giving me several errors.  It is complaining while trying to override the `onCreate()` method.  The exact error is below.  Can anyone explain what mistake I am making here?

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class CheatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
    }

}
```

The exact errors:

```
The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type CheatActivity
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type CheatActivity must override or implement 
a supertype method
```

Comment: As the errors indicate, the code is *not* correct.

Comment: Code is not correct. You need to `extends` `Activity`.

Comment: Stop downvoting, he is just asking for help, and made a mistake. It does not deserve -6 or more.

Comment: @Paul - thank you paul. I don't know why they give me -6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class CheatActivity extends Activity {
```

You should extend from Activity class. Because you are just creating new class without any methods which can be overridden from parent class.

Comment: Thank you. I make a foolish mistake.

Comment: No problem. Good luck in future development!

Answer (score 0):

As Anatol said, you have to add `extends Activity`.

If you didn't know that, the only method you have is implemented when extending from Activity.

I would recommend you to create Activities with your IDE's wizard. And you will avoid having to add them manually to the manifest and adding unimplemented methods.